# problem with CopyDataTable

Tags: c#, datarow

i have a problem.  trehe is code like below..

```
DataRow[] dra = dt_Persons.Select("name = 'Joe'");
dtFiltered = dra.CopyToDataTable();
```

But it gives an error like this **System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'CopyToDataTable' and no extension method 'CopyToDataTable' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found**
So if you know the solution for this error please help me.
Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that method, you need the extension method from the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` namespace (and found in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll); so try adding:

```
using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;
```

to the top of your file. If that doesn't work, add a dll reference to the dll. Then:

```
dtFiltered = dra.CopyToDataTable();
```

should work, assuming `dtFiltered` is typed as a `DataTable`.